# creating a list of properties vs getters and setters in python

Tags: python, properties, getter-setter

```
class OurAtt():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class OurClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__OurAtt = OurAtt()

    @property
    def OurAtt(self):
        return self.__OurAtt

    @OurAtt.setter
    def OurAtt(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            self.__OurAtt = 0
        elif val > 1000:
            self.__OurAtt = 1000
        else:
            self.__OurAtt = val


x = OurClass()
x.OurAtt.Var1 = 1
print x.OurAtt.Var1
```

Questions:

1. How to create a list of 100 variables like x.OurAtt.Var1, x.OurAtt.Var2 .. x.OurAtt.Var100 and assign them initial value 1,2 ....100.
2. Is it possible do to something like this x.OurAtt.Var[1..100] = [1..100]? Basically need List with properties.

Comment: You could achieve that with the built-in method `exec`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec I would however advise against it. What is exactly your user story? Eventually you could create a dictionary, so instead of variables you would have keys and values.

Comment: @cezar Thanks a lot. Conditon is to use only scalor or list or tuple not a dictionary. Could you please help on this?

Comment: You can do something like: `for i in range(1, 101): exec('OurAtt.Var{0} = {0}'.format(i))`. This will give you variables from OurAtt.Var1 to OurAtt.Var100 with initial value of 1 to 100. I still don't think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create individual `varX` properties, no. You can create a new object with [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [`__setitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) methods instead, and use `x.your_attr[X]` subscription notation instead:

```
class ListLike(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = list(range(101))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._values)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._values[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if not 0 <= index < len(self):
            raise IndexError(index)
        self._values[index] = max(0, min(1000, val))
```

then use this as your attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = ListLike()
```

Comment: @Martijin, Thanks a lot. Why can't use properties? Could you please let me know pro's and con's of using?

Comment: @Sana: you can use properties, but creating 100 properties with numbered variables limits you greatly in what you can do with them. Try to access all 100 and do a calculation on them, for example. Using a list-like object is just far more flexible here.